# Query RDF with SPARQL

Tags: linux, open-source, offline, rdf, sparql

I’m looking for a hassle-free way to query [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) with [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL).

It would be great if it’s possible to paste the RDF into a textarea (instead of having to select a file). At best it would support all these ways how to specify the RDF to be queried:

- paste the RDF
- select a local RDF file
- enter a URL to an online RDF file
- load the RDF as specified in the SPARQL query (via `FROM`, or whatever mechanisms SPARQL supports)

The more RDF serializations formats are supported, the better. It should at least support [Turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_%28syntax%29) (but I don’t require this, as I could use a converter if a recommended solution is worth it).

I don’t have any restrictions regarding the result format.

A solution *must*

- be **FLOSS**,
- run natively on **GNU/Linux**, and
- work **offline**.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/) Server, in combination with [RDF4J Workbench](http://rdf4j.org/doc/rdf4j-server-workbench-and-console/rdf4j-workbench/) (disclosure: I am on the RDF4J development team). Eclipse RDF4J was formerly known as OpenRDF Sesame.

Your *must* criteria:

- RDF4J is FLOSS (EDL - [Eclipse Distribution License](https://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php))
- RDF4J runs on GNU/Linux and any other OS (Java)
- RDF4J Server and Workbench work offline (they are webapps, but no internet is needed to contact localhost)

[RDF4J Server](http://rdf4j.org/doc/rdf4j-server-workbench-and-console/installing-rdf4j-server-and-rdf4j-workbench/) is RDF4J's Database Server application, which manages the triplestores and offers access via the RDF4J APIs and via SPARQL.

[RDF4J Workbench](http://rdf4j.org/doc/rdf4j-server-workbench-and-console/rdf4j-workbench/) is a client application that offers many useful functions:

- RDF upload functionality, supporting copy paste in a textarea, upload of a local file, and upload from a URL.
- supports import and export of all common RDF syntax formats, including Turtle.
- a full SPARQL query editor, with syntax hightlight, autocomplete, and saved queries.
- repository explorer functionality.
- SPARQL 1.1 Update functionality allowing you to add/modify/delete RDF via SPARQL.

To install, follow these steps:

1. Install Apache Tomcat on your local machine
2. Download the RDF4J SDK distribution and locate the two war files in it (uncompress and you'll find them in the `war/` directory)
3. Deploy the two war files, `rdf4j-server.war` and `rdf4j-workbench.war`, to your local Tomcat installation.
4. Visit `http://localhost:8080/rdf4j-workbench` to enter the RDF4 Workbench.

Comment: Sesame is now called [rdf4j](http://rdf4j.org/2016/05/18/goodbye-sesame-hello-rdf4j/).

Answer (score 1):

Install a Java SDK and the try [Blazegraph](https://blazegraph.com/). See [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazegraph). It is a triplestore which comes with a web interface which you can reach at localhost:9000

Download it and then install/run it according to the [Quick start guide](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/Quick_Start), which also has a screenshot of the main GUI.

Another advantage of Blazegraph is that it supports federated SPARQL queries.

A disadvantage is that the source code is unmaintained since ~2020.